# How to stop is_callable from displaying includes

Tags: php

I am trying to use `is_callable` to check for class and method existence, it goes very well but keeps displaying my include parameters.

Here is the code:

```
if(!is_callable(array(self::$classy,self::$action))) {
    self::$classy = 'index';
    self::$action = 'index';
}
```

and here is the result:

```
.;C:\php5\pear;./lib;./model;./helper;./controller;/model/;/helper/;/controller/;/lib.
```

This happens only if the return value is true which means the method is not callable or the class is not in the registered autoloadeds.

Any Ideas ???

Comment: Did you put any echo statements in the code?

Comment: Did you or the framework you're using register an autoload function?

Comment: Extrakun :No echo statement inside the if statement.

Comment: Volkerk : I did register autoload functions but not inside the statement

Answer (score 1):

You say you're checking for the existence of classes and methods.. So my first question would be, can't you use `class_exists();` and `method_exists();` for this?

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Another idea for requiring certain methods on a class, would be to use interfaces. Then you'd only need to make sure the class exists, and PHP should give some messages if the methods that you've defined in your interface aren't available in said class.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: I want to check for the class existence in many folders at the same time,the folders that I have registered using spl_autoload_register and  class_exists() require the class to be autoloaded first and require other code to look for the directory which is a lot of code.

Comment: I use `spl_autoload_register` with multiple directories as well, what I do is just create a index of possible classNames (and I can configure a prefix for a className per directory for example). This way you don't have to search every time a class is requested, just ask the index. Combined in two functions (indexing, loading class) it's just 87 lines of code (unfortunately, I can't share it due to company policies.)

Comment: Class Names is not my choice, it is the user's input  So I cannot index , I am extracting the variables from the requested url

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

> ob_start(); //activate outputbuffering (prevents the server from sending anything to the client)
>
> if(!is_callable(array(self::$classy,self::$action)))
>   {
>
> ```
> self::$classy = 'index';
> self::$action = 'index';
> ```
>
> }
>
> ob_end_clean(); //end outputbuffering and discard any output that was generated

Comment: This the last step I will take if no other solution available